# php function return blank value on return statement and print right on echo

Tags: php

i create this function for search resume file from directory, if resume is available then function return full path, problem is function return nothing if i use "return", if i use "echo" then it will print right path

```
 function search_resume($resume,$dir="uploads/resumes")
{
    $root = scandir($dir);
    foreach($root as $value)
    {
        /* echo $value."<br/>"; */
        if($value === '.' || $value === '..') {continue;} 
        if(is_file("$dir/$value"))
        {
            if($value==$resume)
            {
                $path="$dir/$value";
                return $path;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            search_resume($resume,"$dir/$value");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the point of this function? if you know what dir to look under, _and_ you know the file-name, why yould you bneed this recursive function to scan directories N levels deep?

Comment: You're ignoring `search_resume()` return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very typical, basic problem with recursive functions: you need to `return` recursive calls as well, they're not going to `return` themselves.

```
    ...
    else {
        $path = search_resume($resume,"$dir/$value");
        if ($path) {
            return $path;
        }
    }
```